# Filter rows based on window functions

Tags: sql, filter, amazon-athena, presto, row-number

Is there a way to filter out rows based on a a window function over `row_number` in the same select statement?

Currently, what I'm doing is,

```
SELECT other_columns,row_id_ranked FROM (
  SELECT other_columns, "row_number"() OVER (
        PARTITION BY "uuid"
        ORDER BY "uuid" ASC, "status"."sequence" DESC
    ) "row_id_ranked",
  FROM my_table 
  )
WHERE row_id_ranked = 1
```

But this means Presto will create a temporary inner table to and calculate the "row_id_ranked", which means extra work.

is there a way to filter out the rows within the same select statement?
Something like,

```
    "status"."sequence" FILTER(
       WHERE (   
        "row_number"()
            OVER (
                PARTITION BY "uuid"
                ORDER BY "uuid" ASC,
                    "status"."sequence" DESC
            ) 
         ) = 1
    ) "sequence_num",
```

Comment: Now you only get 1s in this row ....

Comment: this is to steal mssql or some engine sql ?

Comment: Well, the query I gave was just demo'ing the filtering logic only, the original query selects more than a hundred columns.

Comment: The query runs on AWS Athena. It uses Presto as querying engine.

Comment: Ok . i can write in sql . you will need to set the row_id_ranked  value directly to  where.

Comment: In general, over time, this will be O (2 * N) (). affects almost imperceptible time. (O(N) one select time )